# Query with multiple values in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like:

```
id     name            children
1      Roberto         Michael,Dia
2      Maria           John,Alex
3      Mary            Alexandre,Diana
```

My problem is;
I want to find who has a child named Alex.

I can't use `"where children = 'Alex'"` in SQL because I have more than one names in same cells.

So I use `"where children LIKE '%Alex%'"` - that looks smart but
in the same time i get all start like Alex :( Alexandre 
or i want to get dia but result is dia and diana :(

how can I get single Alex in that data type?

I hope I can explain my problem with my terrible english :D

Comment: See normalization. It's pretty fundamental to relational databases.

Comment: Not a good idea to have a number of children under a table field. It would be better to create a second table where the names of the children are stored and join it to your main table by using a foreign key.

Comment: Strawberry and kidA are both saying the same thing: you need to break out "children" into a separate table, then link it back to "parents".  The process is called "[normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)".  The "link" between parents and children is called a "[foreign key](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.htm)".

Comment: And so is FoggyDay ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution would be to normalize your schema. You should have a separate table with one row for each child, instead of a comma-delimited list. Then you can join with this table to find parent with a specific child. See @themite's answer for an example of this.

But if you can't do that for some reason, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Alex', children)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the data into two tables.

the first would look like this

```
ID    Name
1     Roberto
2     Maria
3     Mary
```

And the second like this

```
ParentId     child
1            Michael
1            Dia
2            John
2            Alex
```

and so on.

then you could do the query you want without having to worry about `like`  and your data is much more useable

Answer (score 0):

That's why you'd want to have two tables here.

```
parents:
id  name
1   Roberto  
2   Maria
3   Mary

children:
id  parentid name
1   1        Michael
2   1        Dia
3   2        John
4   2        Alex
5   3        Alexandre
6   3        Diana
```

And now you can query this much more effectively with a join or an exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parents
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Children 
    WHERE parentid=Parents.id 
      AND Children.name='Alex'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather make different tables for children and parents something like this.

Table for parents

```
parent_id     name            
1             Roberto         
2             Maria           
3             Mary
```

Table for children

```
children_id  parent_id  name
1            1          Michael     
2            1          Dia 
3            2          John
```

.... and so on

Comment: I'm just making fun of your idiom :-)

Comment: Well I didn't want to get technical with him as it seem like he doesn't know much (based on his question).