# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) when select from two table

Tags: mysql

i had this error when i used this query

```
   SELECT id,title,files,price,auction_start,
   (SELECT * FROM `phi_files` where  id in(d.files) order by id desc limit 1)
   FROM phi_ads d Where cat=1 GROUP BY id DESC Limit 6
```

I have two table phi_ads table have ads , and phi_files have images files , i try to take one file for each ad

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a subquery is used as an expression, it can only return one value. So the query has to return a single row, and that row has to have a single column.

You solved the multiple row problem by using `LIMIT 1`. To solve the multiple column problem, change `*` to the specific column that you need.

I also wonder why you're using `WHERE id IN (d.files)`. Since there's only one value in the list, it should be `WHERE id = d.files`. Or if `d.files` is a comma-separated list (as I suspect from the column name), you need to use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, d.files)`. See [Query with multiple values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639692/query-with-multiple-values-in-a-column/28639762#28639762).

Comment: sometime d.files contain (20,21,22,23) as text

Comment: Putting comma-separated lists in columns is poor design, you should normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the `id` is  duplicate in both table try in sub select `phi_files.id`

```
SELECT id,title,files,price,auction_start,
   (SELECT * FROM `phi_files` where  phi_files.id in(phi_ads.files) order by phi_files.id desc limit 1)
   FROM phi_ads Where cat=1 GROUP BY id DESC Limit 6
```

Comment: How does this help with the error, which is that `SELECT *` is returning more than 1 column.

Comment: i just change * to id , work fine thanks for both