# i want fetch the multiple data available in single row-column of table using query how to do that?

Tags: php, database

i have a table into the database named as country which contains the university name, stream, entrance exam and cutoff.
i want to select the universities from tabel and for that i'm using the query as,

```
SELECT university_name FROM country WHERE stream = ms AND entrance_exam = GMAT OR MS;
```

i want university_name from table where stream is ms when i select GMAT OR MS in dropdown. please solve my problem and tell how to do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwdc9.png)

Comment: It's bad design to put comma-separated lists in database columns. You should normalize your data.

Comment: why dont you seperate stream into its own table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put `OR` right after an `=` test. If you want to test a single column against multiple values, you need to repeat the test, e.g.

```
stream = 'ms' OR stream = 'mba'
```

In SQL there's a shortcut for this:

```
stream IN ('ms', 'mba')
```

However, this won't work for your design, because you have a comma-separated list. To test for membership, you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`, and there's no shortcut for multiple tests.

```
SELECT university_name
FROM country
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('ms', stream) OR FIND_IN_SET('mba', stream))
AND (FIND_IN_SET('GMAT', entrance_exam) OR FIND_IN_SET('MS', entrance_exam))
```

See [Query with multiple values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639692/query-with-multiple-values-in-a-column/28639762#28639762)

Make sure you put parenthese around each `OR` expression when they're mixed with `AND`. See [SQL statement is ignoring where parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663976/sql-statement-is-ignoring-where-parameter)

It would be much better if you normalized the data instead of using comma-separated lists. You should have a `university_stream` table with rows like:

```
university_name     stream
pune university     ms
pune university     mba
Acadia University   ms
Acadia University   mba
```

and a `university_entrance` table with rows like:

```
university_name     exam
pune university     GMAT
pune university     MS
Acadia University   GMAT
Acadia University   MS
```

Then you would join the tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.university_name
FROM university_stream AS a
JOIN university_entrance AS b ON a.university_name = b.university_name
WHERE a.stream IN ('ms', 'mba')
AND b.exam IN ('GMAT', 'MS')
```